# Modify a JavaScript variable with Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have a boolean JavaScript variable named `foo` that I would like to change the value of from true to false. The variable has global scope.

In Selenium, how can I change the value of this variable?

(The variable, hidden to the user, disables a CPU-intensive feature that causes Selenium to choke.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You didn't specify a language and Selenium tool, so...

Java + Selenium WebDriver

```
// assuming JS is enabled for this driver instance
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.foo = false;");
```

Java + Selenium RC

```
selenium.getEval("window.foo = false;")
```

C# + Selenium WebDriver

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.foo = false;");
```

Comment: Thanks. The language I'm using for Selenium is Java.

Comment: for Python also, please. I am using Python + Webdriver